# Where to set HBase JVM options？

Tags: java, jvm, hbase, heap-memory

Is there any way to set the `JVM` options , like `-XX:HeapDumpPath=./java_pid<pid>.hprof` for `HBase`?

And I am using `Ambari`, is there any way to set it globally by using `Ambari`?

Answer (score 3):

In "*HBase the Definitive Guide*" of *Lars George*

```
$HABASE_HOME/conf/hbase-env.sh

hbase-env.sh
You set HBase environment variables in this file. Examples include options to pass to
the JVM when an HBase daemon starts, such as Java heap size and garbage collector
configurations. You also set options for HBase configuration, log directories, niceness,
SSH options, where to locate process pid files, and so on. Open the file at conf/hbaseenv.
sh and peruse its content. Each option is fairly well documented. Add your own
environment variables here if you want them read when an HBase daemon is started.
Changes here will require a cluster restart for HBase to notice the change.†
```